# Programming ruby from a web browser

Tags: ruby

[_why](http://tryruby.hobix.com/) enables you to run ruby (irb in particular) from a web browser, and [github](http://github.com) allows you to edit code that's under version control from a web browser.

Is there anything that allows you to do both, ie edit code and run it, from a web browser?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [herokugarden](http://herokugarden.com/) ?

Comment: Can that work if the program you are working on is a command-line program (as opposed to rails and the like)?

Comment: It includes a command-line console (yes, through the broswer), so I don't see why not.  I haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with editing locally, commiting, and having a git hook that pushes the latest version to the correct location?

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: Even when your local computer doesn't have ruby installed on it?